# 554 Transaction failed: Duplicate header 'Reply-To'

Tags: email, smtp, amazon-ses

I just switched from Gmail SMTP to Amazon SES SMTP for sending out transactional mails. After switching, I got the error below which I was not getting with Gmail:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't overwrite cause with com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 554 Transaction failed: Duplicate header 'Reply-To'.

    at java.lang.Throwable.initCause(Throwable.java:456)
    at javax.mail.MessagingException.setNextException(MessagingException.java:51)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:109)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:48)


    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 554 Transaction failed: Duplicate header 'Reply-To'.

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2108)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.finishData(SMTPTransport.java:1889)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1120)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:95)
    ... 5 more
```

Here are my observations while trying to figure out the problem:

(1) If I specify a single email address in the "Reply-TO" header, this error does not happen.

(2) If I specify multiple  email address address in the "Reply-TO" header, this error happens.

Ideas will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Heres what worked for me:

**I changed code from**

```
   MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

   message.setReplyTo(new InternetAddress[1]);
```

**To**

```
   message.setHeader("Reply-To",replyTo.trim());
```

This allowed me to have multiple addresses in the replyTo header.